# Achieve Keepalived VRRP in public cloud using Strongswan IPSec

Tags: strongswan, keepalived, virtual-ip

I am trying to setup VRRP failover for PostgreSQL using Keepalived Active-Passive mode in one of the public clouds. The known limitation of this cloud is it does not work with VRRP out of the box (hosts within LAN cannot ping VIPs installed on another hosts).

Initially, my network looked like this:

```
172.16.1.3 ---- | 172.16.1.4 | ---- | 172.17.1.4 |
IPSec gateway     PG Primary          PG Standby
                  (Keepalived)        (Keepalived)

* Keepalived VIP = 192.168.2.100
* "--" is VPC LAN
```

Keepalived installs VIP 192.168.2.100 on PG Primary. If the Primary node goes down, VIP is moved to Standby node. However this installed VIP cannot be contacted by any of the hosts within VPC network (I received confirmation it's a limitation by cloud provider).

I thought installing IPSec overlay within VPC network using Strongswan might help to overcome this limitation, because Strongswan works with [Virtual IPs](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/features/vip.html). So now network looks like this:

```
172.16.1.3 ==== | 172.16.1.4 | ---- | 172.17.1.4 | ==== 172.16.1.3 
IPSec gateway     PG Primary          PG Standby        IPSec gateway
                  (Keepalived)        (Keepalived)

* Keepalived VIP = 192.168.2.100
* "--" is VPC LAN, "==" is IPsec over VPC LAN
```

IPSec gateway is connected to both PostgreSQL nodes.

Here's excerpt from `/etc/swanctl/conf.d/connections.conf` on 172.16.1.3 (conn-defaults and children-defaults are omitted).

```
connections {
      pg1 : conn-defaults, children-defaults {
              remote_addrs = 172.16.1.4
              remote {
                      id = pg1
              }
              children {
                      net-net {
                              local_ts = 172.16.1.3/32
                              remote_ts = 192.168.2.0/24
                      }
              }
      }
      pg2 : conn-defaults, children-defaults {
              remote_addrs = 172.17.1.4
              remote {
                      id = pg2
              }
              children {
                      net-net {
                              local_ts = 172.17.1.3/32
                              remote_ts = 192.168.2.0/24
                      }
              }
      }
}
```

And this is connections.conf on 172.16.1.4 and 172.17.1.4 (they are mostly identical):

```
connections {
        gw : conn-defaults, children-defaults {
                remote_addrs = 172.16.1.3
                remote {
                        id = gw
                }
                children {
                        net-net {
                                local_ts = 192.168.2.0/24
                                remote_ts = 172.16.1.3/32
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

As a result, I'm able to query PostgreSQL on VIP from Gateway successfully (and gateway's clients can do as well), but only if VIP is installed on PG Primary (172.16.1.4). I guess that's because pg1 connection is defined before pg2 connection in `/etc/swanctl/conf.d/connections.conf` on the Gateway.

If I change connections order in .conf file or terminate IPsec connection to pg1, I'm able to connect to VIP installed on PG Standby (172.17.1.4) as well. Is there any way to lookup VIP address on both hosts if they share the same traffic selector (`local_ts`)?

Comment: I figured, I can just monitor state of keepalived nodes and start / terminate ipsec connections using swanctl or vici